# If you had an equation where x^x = y where x is a positive number that is not 0 or 1, can there ever be more than 1 value of x?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, lambert-w

<strike>If $x^x = 1$, both $0$ and $1$ would satisfy $x$. Does this mean $0 = 1$?</strike>.

If you had an equation where $x^x = y$ where $x$ is a positive number that is not $0$ or $1$, can there ever be more than $1$ value of $x$?

Comment: Does $x^2 = 1 \Leftrightarrow x = \pm 1$ mean $1 = -1$?

Comment: Ok what about my second question?

Comment: Also note that $0^0$ is not really a well defined. You can, however, take the one sided limit $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^x=1$$

Comment: To formalize it a little: $x^x = y \Leftrightarrow f(x) = y$, where $f(x) = x^x$. Now, there exists an $y$ so that there are multiple solutions exactly then if $f(x)$ isn't injective

Answer (score 1):

This is a fun function to play with. I had a minor obsession with it before i took calculus. Yes there are y-values with more than one x-value located on $(0,1)$ Note the global min of this as a real function is when $x=e^{-1}$

[image: plot of $y=x^x$]

Comment: Is that gradient constant between 0.3 & 0.4?

Comment: @Yaya I don't think gradient makes sense in this case. If you mean is the slope of the tangent line constant between .3 and .4 No. The derivative evaluated at a point is equal to the slope of the tangent line. Here is the derivative $$y=x^x(1+\ln x)$$ which is definitely NOT constant. Note that there is a zero sloped tangent line at $e^{-1} \approx 0.367879441171442$

Comment: Here's the fun bored exercise that led me to this function. I typed $\sqrt[2]{2}$ on my calculator and then hit $\sqrt[Ans]{2}$ a bunch of times. I was familair that hitting the square root of answer repeatedly converged  to 1, but wasn't sure what this converged to. Turns out it converges to approximately $x \approx 1.55961046946237$ which you can check $x^x \approx 2$. This process doesn't work for all starting points, some get caught in loops and it's really slow, but it's an insight I'm proud of my 16 year old self for :)

Answer (score 1):

For any point $x_1$ in the range $[0,1]$, there is another point $x_2$ in the same range such that:
$$x_1^{x_1}= x_2^{x_2}$$

Comment: any point except $x=e^{-1}$ ;)

Comment: @N8tron - correct.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, $0^0$ is NOT equal to $1$; instead, it is undefined. Even if $0$ did satisfy the equation, it would not imply that $1=0$. $-1^2=1$ and $1^1=1$, but this does not imply that $-1=1$. They are merely two distinct solutions to the equation $x^2=1$

To answer your second question, it is possible for, for example, $y=0.75$

Comment: Please note that $-1^2$ does not equal $1$.  But $(-1)^2$ does.